# Consulta no ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Eu tenho esse relacionamento

[image: teste].

Como eu faço para consultar no `ActiveRecord` para retornar os dados de `Works`, `WorkZei` e `Wi_schools`?

Eu tentei assim:

```
r = Responsible.find(1)

students = r.students

students.each {|s| s.school.joins(:works,:work_zeis).all }
```

Resulta no seguinte erro:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `joins'
```

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes de seu problema? fica mais fácil ajudar. No seu caso realmente vai dar erro, por school é um objeto e não um ActiveRecordAssociation então não faz sentido você fazer joins ai.

Explique melhor qual o objetivo do seu código! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Responsible.where(id: 1).joins(students: [ school: [ :works, :work_zeis ] ]).first
```